# AWS EC2 instance self hosted webapi install ssl certificate

Tags: amazon-ec2, ssl-certificate

I have a self hosted rest api on a windows EC2 instance in AWS which is being used by a mobile application. I would like to install a certificate to make the http calls go over ssl layer.

I also have a domain and a website hosted on bluehost.com (hosting provider) which is not using the api at all.

From what I searched and understood is that I can create a free AWS certificate via the cert manager and add it to a load balancer that will sit in front of my EC2 instance, then create a subdomain for my domain on bluehost.com which will redirect the traffic to the load balancer. (Correct me if I'm wrong here)

I would like to skip the load balancer and also use my own positive SSL certificate instead of the one that is offered by the cert manager on AWS. Is there a way to achieve this? If yes, could you please provide the steps that I would have to follow?

Comment: Are you using IIS. If yes, you can configure the SSL on IIS. https://knowledge.digicert.com/solution/SO14925.html. if not can you give more details such as what technology

Comment: I’m using selfhosted Microsoft Owin WebApi. But regardless, my question is not about how to install an ssl certificate on a server. My ssl certificate is issued to a domain name which is not related to the EC2 hostname or IP adress. If I install directly the certificate on that EC2 instance where the rest api is the domain name will not match and certificate will appear as invalid

Comment: There will be no mismatch if you have the cert for `api.example.com` (or `*.example.com`)

Comment: @DusanBajic, I have an ssl certificate issued to www.example.com. I have a  website which resides on bluehost ( where I obtained my domain and created a website ) and my rest api is on an EC2 instance. Could you explain to me all the steps that I need to take in order to achieve what I described above ?

Comment: You should probably have separate subdomain/hostname for your api (like `api.example.com`) if you are going to host it on different platform, and you will  need certificate for that name. You will need an entry in you DNS, to point that name to your EC2 instance (or load balancer, if you prefer that)

Comment: @DusanBajic thank you for the help I got a Wildcard ssl cert and your suggestion actually worked